# Pointers, am I using them correctly? Objective-c/cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, pointers, garbage-collection

I have this in my @interface

```
struct track currentTrack;
struct track previousTrack;
int anInt;
```

Since these are not objects, I do not have to have them like int* anInt right?
And if setting non-object values like ints, boolean, etc, I do not have to release the old value right (assuming non-GC environment)?

The struct contains objects:

```
typedef struct track {
NSString* theId;
NSString* title;
} *track;
```

Am I doing that correctly?

Lastly, I access the struct like this:

```
[currentTrack.title ...];
currentTrack.theId = @"asdf"; //LINE 1
```

I'm also manually managing the memory (from a setter) for the struct like this:

```
[currentTrack.title autorelease];
currentTrack.title = [newTitle retain];
```

If I'm understanding the garbage collection correctly, I should be able to ditch that and just set it like LINE 1 (above)?

Also with garbage collection, I don't need a dealloc method right?
If I use garbage collection does this mean it only runs on OS 10.5+? And any other thing I should know before I switch to garbage collected code?

Sorry there are so many questions. Very new to objective-c and desktop programming.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have this in my @interface
>
> ```
> struct track currentTrack;
> struct track previousTrack;
> int anInt;
> ```
>
> Since these are not objects, I do not have to have them like `int* anInt` right?

That would declare a pointer to an `int` stored somewhere else.

> And if setting non-object values like ints, boolean, etc, I do not have to release the old value right (assuming non-GC environment)?

`release` is a message. You can only send a message to a Cocoa (or, in some cases, Core Foundation) object.

> The struct contains objects:
>
> ```
> typedef struct track {
>     NSString* theId;
>     NSString* title;
> ```

More precisely, it contains pointers to objects.

You can't ever have an object stored directly in a variable; you can only allocate it dynamically by sending an `alloc` message to a class, and receive the pointer to the allocated instance. Similarly, you can only send a message to a pointer to an object; you cannot and should not dereference a pointer to an object.

For these reasons, we almost always elide the “a pointer to”. We speak of the pointers as if they are the objects, but, in precise truth, they are not.

> ```
> } *track;
> ```

That's correct if you want to declare the `track` type as being a pointer to a `struct track`. Generally, this will confuse people.

> Lastly, I access the struct like this:
>
> ```
> [currentTrack.title ...];
> currentTrack.theId = @"asdf"; //LINE 1
> ```

So the previous line is line 0? ;)

> I'm also manually managing the memory (from a setter) for the struct like this:
>
> ```
> [currentTrack.title autorelease];
> currentTrack.title = [newTitle retain];
> ```
>
> If I'm understanding the garbage collection correctly, I should be able to ditch that and just set it like LINE 1 (above)?

If you're using garbage collection, then the `autorelease` and `retain` messages will do nothing, so yes, the plain assignment and the assignment with (ineffectual) release and retain messages are equivalent.

I do question why you're putting this information in a structure and not a [model object](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ModelObjects/), though.

> Also with garbage collection, I don't need a dealloc method right? If I use garbage collection does this mean it only runs on OS 10.5+? And any other thing I should know before I switch to garbage collected code?

Yes: Read the [Garbage Collection Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/GarbageCollection/). It tells you everything you need to know, including the answers to the previous two questions.

As for pointers, you may want to read [my pointers tutorial](http://boredzo.org/pointers/). The title says C, but everything in C is also true in Objective-C.

Answer (score 2):

Although you seem to understand this stuff all right in general, I'd strongly recommand against storing objects in a struct. Getting proper memory management for that will be very troublesome — because even though the struct itself doesn't require memory management, the objects still do, and unless the struct is only ever accessed through a function API (essentially making it s poor man's object), you're going to have a tough time ensuring that happens. Like Peter said, that makes sense to be a model object.

Comment: True in general. However, since GC is in use here, there will be little, if anything, needing to be done in the name of memory management (besides careful thought).

Answer (score 0):

Correct, correct, no, yes, correct, yes, and Apple's Garbage Collection Programming Guide is a good read.